Error when "sunbeam cluster join" command
I get this error when trying to connect node. This is new installation. Sunbeam03 is a master node.
An unexpected error has occurred. Please run 'sunbeam inspect' to generate an inspection report.
Error: End Of File (EOF). Exception style platform.
<pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0x7fd299636260>
command: /snap/openstack/584/juju/bin/juju
args: ['/snap/openstack/584/juju/bin/juju', 'login', '--user', 'sunbeam01']
buffer (last 100 chars): b''
before (last 100 chars): b'\x1b[91mERROR\x1b[0m no current controller\r\n'
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: True
pid: 8445
child_fd: 19
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(b'^please enter password')

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong?

So what happens when you enter sunbeam inspect, as the error message suggests?
